# SVG animate not working in Asp.net MVC Application/ Asp.net Web Application (IE -10,9 browser) but working in JS fiddle

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-svg

I have created simple MVC3 application with SVG line/path animation. Please refer below code snippet.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="curtainClip">
            <rect id="clipRect" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>

    <animate xlink:href="#clipRect"
        attributeName="width" 
        dur="15s"
        from="0" 
        to="100" />

    <path clip-path="url(#curtainClip)" stroke="red" d="M 0 0 L 100 100"/>
</svg>
```

it is working in JS-fiddle /JS- bin. that means the animated path will be the result.

Please refer below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/XbzRX/2/

Sample Link:

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/Support/DirectTrac/85008/MvcApplication21320891637.zip)

Animate not working in IE browser.(10,9)

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Do you see any errors show up in the console (accessed via the developer tools)?

Comment: The problem in IE browser only. it displays warning message like tat below in IE.                                                  HTML1500: Tag cannot be self-closing. Use an explicit closing tag. otherwise no error displayed in console.

Comment: I believe those warnings are unrelated, but they mean IE expects closing tags instead of self-closing tags on your elements. Eg. <path ...></path> instead of <path ... />.

Answer (score 0):

IE9/10 does not support declarative SVG animation. It does, however, support CSS animation of some style attributes, and scripted animation.

[See here - Basic SVG Animation (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg193979%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)